# Java HQL Issues with GroupBy/Having Query

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I have to make a HQL using Hibernate to find out the sum of some frequencies of Museum Vigilants to their museums, some museum vigilants occupy the same shift per hour - I want to find Mike Jones frequency in this shift.

This is what I have so far:

```
select v, m.freq/count(m.id) from Vigilant v inner join v.museums as
m group by m.id having count(m.id) > 0 and v.forename = 'Mike Jones'
```

This will get me a list of Objects in Hibernate with an Vigilant and a number - the numbers I have gotten are correct and I wish to SUM them up - i.e. I want to SUM(m.freq/count(m.id)) and return that as a HQL to hibernate.

I've tried multiple ways, I devised a SQL solution following this path and subqueries but HQL doesn't allow subqueries in the FROM clause which set me back to this. Now I have no idea how because adding SUM or removing v from the select statement doesn't work.

Any help with how I can get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: do the summing in java or use a native query

Comment: I can't use a native query. I can't do the summing in Java either. These are some constraints I have been given, I need it to be a HQL string.

Comment: they sound a bit like arbitray restrictions, have a separate query for the summing, and pass in appropriate values

Comment: Unfortunately I am subject to these restrictions :( I will try your suggestion though, thanks. Edit: I can't do that either, this is how my task was assigned, it needs to be one query string :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't group by whole entities](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-grouping):

> Neither the group by clause nor the order by clause can contain
>   arithmetic expressions. Hibernate also does not currently expand a
>   grouped entity, so you cannot write group by cat if all properties of
>   cat are non-aggregated. You have to list all non-aggregated properties
>   explicitly.

So your query becomes something like this:

```
select 
    v.id,
    v.prop1
    ...,
    v.propn,
    m.freq/count(m.id)
from Vigilant v 
inner join v.museums m
where 
    v.forename = 'Mike Jones'
group by v.id, v.prop1, .., v.propn
```

1. The prop1...propn are all properties of a Vigilant (EAGER fetching complicate it further)
2. The `having` is not necessary because you already have an INNER JOIN and not Vigilant is returned if there's no Museum
3. The `forename` filter makes more sense in the WHERE clause

My advice is to use a simpler query:

```
select 
    v.id,
    m.freq/count(m.id)
from Vigilant v 
inner join v.museums m
where 
    v.forename = 'Mike Jones'
group by v.id
```

And use the selected ids to retrieve the entities with a second query:

```
select v 
from Vigilant v 
where v.id in (:ids)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! I decided to go down an alternative route in modifying my POJOs to calculate this information on the fly (which I am allowed to do). :) Your advice sounds good though.